Integrating Rabbitmq with react native
I am currently working on an Android and iOS application for an IoT device, where I need to integrate RabbitMQ with my React Native application. I have tried using amqplib, but I encountered numerous dependency issues that I couldn't resolve. I also attempted to use various third-party libraries, but they are outdated and do not support React Native version 0.71.
If anyone can help with the integration, it would be greatly appreciated!
Would you like assistance with resolving the integration issues as well?
I used react-native-rabbitmq and got these errors:


